# Oracle database link to MySQL database on RedHat Linux

Tags: mysql, oracle-11g-r2, database-link, redhat

I have an Oracle 11g database on a RedHat server and also have MySQL database on another RedHat server. I want to create a link to the MySQL server from the Oracle which allows me to execute queries in MySQL from Oracle.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle can connect to MySql with an ODBC connector.  This is described in some detail [here](http://www.pythian.com/news/1554/how-to-access-mysql-from-oracle-with-odbc-and-sql/).  Also see the official Oracle documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/gateways.112/e12070/toc.htm).

This will work for Oracle 10 and 11g to MySQL 4.1, 5.0, 5.1 or 6.0.  There are limitations both in performance and what you can do.  My understanding is

- no distributed transactions
- no insert as select .....
- treat numbers as numbers and strings as strings, this is not the place for implicit type casts
- as you might expect non-Oracle features are not supported
- no Oracle DDL is supported
- these functions are supported AVG(exp), LIKE(exp), COUNT(*), MAX(exp), MIN(exp), NOT

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to do that is to write a [UDF](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions231.htm) in Java. Oracle itself won't be able to connect to a MySQL server.